# Moving view offscreen at load time not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an audio player view at the bottom of my application. I want this audio player view to hide with a slide animation at the bottom of the screen once it finishes the last item in the playlist. At the start of the application, I need this audioplayer view to be hidden until the user taps an audio file to play.

The issue I am having is that the audioplayer view won't move offscreen at the beginning of the VC loading.

What's odd is that I have a similar function that moves the audioplayer view offscreen correctly, and everything works fine. This seems like it is only an issue at load time - that initial hiding of the audioplayer view.

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear 
    footerView.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear  
    footerView.playButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
    footerView.playButton.borderColor = UIColor.red

    initializeFooterView()

    ...
}

//print statements called @viewDidLoad, but not the translate function
func initializeFooterView(){

    print("initFooterView", String(describing: footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y))

    print(String(describing: footerView.frame.size.height))

    footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y += footerView.frame.size.height

    print("initFooterView", String(describing: footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y))

}

//Working function to show/hide audioplayer view... works during runtime
func hideShowFooterView(){

    let animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = .curveEaseOut
    let keyframeAnimationOptions: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)

    if let footerView = self.footerView{

        if (footerView.superview?.isHidden)!{

            footerView.superview?.isHidden = false
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: keyframeAnimationOptions , animations: {() in
                footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y -= (footerView.superview?.frame.size.height)!

            }, completion: nil)

        }else{

            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: keyframeAnimationOptions , animations: {() in
                footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y += (footerView.superview?.frame.size.height)!

            }, completion: { (completed) in

                if completed{
                    footerView.superview?.isHidden = true

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Cleaned up print statements called from initializeFooterView() that moves audioPlayer view offscreen within viewDidLoad():

```
initFooterView() - footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y: 0.0
initFooterView() - footerView.frame.size.height = 75.0
initFooterView() - footerView.superview?.frame.origin.y: 75
```

If you're wondering why I translate the view on y by footerView.frame.size.height in initializeFooterView(), but translate the view by footerView.**superview**.frame.size.height in the hideShowFooterView(), it's because the height of the superview at viewDidLoad is 763, for some reason, while the height of the footerView's frame is 75 (the correct amount). It translates correctly during runtime, however, so I use the footerView's superview.frame.

**Hierarchy of my views:**

[image: FooterViewController hierarchy]

**Container view set up:** (footerviewcontroller is segued from a container view... not sure if that's influential)

[image: Footerviewcontroller belongs to a containerview]

I have a feeling that there is a conflict in defining my footerview within a storyboard, then trying to change it programmatically during viewDidLoad(). I don't want to have to define everything about footerView programmatically, though :/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to see what you're doing... Are you setting constraints on the `footerView` but then explicitly setting the frame? If so, that might be part of the issue.

However, since you say it's working fine in `hideShowFooterView()`, try moving `initializeFooterView()` from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewWillAppear()`